# Why can only CMake project on Android Studio do code completion?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, ndk-build

Now, I have two project from the following sample code.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk

#### 1. hello-jni as a CMake project from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni

Code completion works correctly like following.

[image: code completion]

#### 2. hello-jni as a ndkBuild project from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/other-builds/ndkbuild/hello-jni

Code completion does not work at all.

[image: no completion]

Why can only CMake project on Android Studio do code completion? And I wanna know how to display code completion for ndk-build project.

Comment: File a bug: http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs

Comment: Thanks! I did it. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=266589